# random walk on finite cyclic group

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, probability-theory, representation-theory, random-walk

Suppose that I have a random walk on the finite cyclic group of order $d > 2$, where the initial probability distribution $Q$ assigns the values $p, q, r$ to $-1, 0, 1$, respectively, where $p + q + r = 1$. I understand the behavior quite well when $p, q, r$ are taken to be all ${1\over3}$, but I don't understand it as well here.

For which values of $p, q, r$ does the corresponding random walk converge to the uniform distribution?

When we do have convergence, what is the rate of convergence?

For which values of $p, q, r$ is this rate maximized? Minimized?

Comment: This is the initial probability distribution. What is the distribution of the steps?

Comment: @YoniMiller Do you really intend $Q$ as an initial probability distribution and not a probability distribution on steps; if so, what's the distribution on steps? Or do you intend $p, q, r$ at $-1,0,1$ to be the probability distribution on the steps that are taken, say with an initial distribution concentrated the identity? (The latter is what my answer uses as an example.)

Answer (score 3):

This is just an answer to the first question on when the random walk converges to the uniform distribution.

See Theorem 2.1 and Proposition 2.3 in [this article by Laurent Saloff-Coste](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/rwfg.pdf):

Consider a left-invariant random walk on a finite group $G$, and let by $\Sigma \subset G$ the set of steps (right multiplications) which have non-zero probability.

(This is the situation in your case, and $\Sigma$ is the subset of $\{-1,0,1\} \subset \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ corresponding to the elements for which the probability is non-zero.)

Then this random walk converges to the uniform distribution if:

1) $\Sigma$ generates $G$

and

2) $\Sigma$ is not contained in a coset of a proper normal subgroup of $G$

In the case of a finite cyclic group and $\Sigma \subset \{-1,0,1\}$, the conclusion would be that these hold as long as $\Sigma$ contains at least two elements unless $\Sigma = \{-1,1\}$ and the order of the group is even.

Comment: Sorry but this is really taking a sledge hammer to kill a fly.

Comment: @Did Do you have a much simpler proof in mind?  You can see what the distribution of total steps becomes in $\mathbb{Z}$, but then when you take it modulo $n$, there are subtleties. For example, the steps of $\{-1,1\}$ with even $n$ case shows that you can't just be naive with some smoothed version of the steps using CLT say.

Comment: "Do you have a much simpler proof in mind?" Yes, for suitable values of d and suitable distributions of the steps (which we still do not know), this process should be a finite irreducible aperiodic Markov chain, and the convergence in distribution of these is proved in every first chapter of notes on the subject.

Comment: @Did If you check the link, Theorem 2.1 is precisely that, and the group stuff follows quickly.

Comment: I did "follow the link" (in fact I know this text), the thing is that the group aspect, which LSC dissects so aptly, is irrelevant to the present question. If one wants to mention the general result that irreducible aperiodic Markov chains converge in distribution, let us choose a reference which does not focus on results of a much higher level, valid in a restricted context.

Comment: I think nice to mention the clean, general group theory result. The poster tagged the question representation theory, so I doubt the group theory is the limiting factor here. In any case, if you have insights on the poster's second and third questions, let's discuss that instead of this.

Comment: Ah, I had missed the (representation-theory) tag, if it was included on purpose then, as you say, this might change the context. Anyway, AFAIAC, I am waiting for a description of the distribution of the steps.